# Поворот повторяющейся текстуры (паттерна) в OpenGL

Tags: opengl, текстура

В картографическом приложении некоторые области заполнены определенным паттерном.
Необходимо чтобы рисунок паттерна вращался вместе с камерой (т.е. всегда был параллельным камере).
Расчет текстурных координат, а также поворот (попытка) происходят в вершинном шейдере.

```
#pattern.vert 
// расчет координат 
v_coord.x = a_position.x*u_proj_scale/u_tex_size.x;
v_coord.y = 1.0 -a_position.y*u_proj_scale/u_tex_size.y;

//поворот
float uniformAngle = radians(u_rotation);
float cos_factor = cos(uniformAngle);
float sin_factor = sin(uniformAngle);
v_coord = vec2((v_coord.x - 0.5) , (v_coord.y - 0.5)) * mat2(cos_factor, sin_factor, -sin_factor, cos_factor);
```

На удивление для квадратных текстур, это работает. Но, если повторяющаяся текстура не квадратная, то при повороте она меняет пропорции. (сжимается или растягивается).
На первом изображении показана область карты с неквадратным паттерном, при повороте - 0 градусов (диспропорций нет). На втором при повороте на 90 градусов (видны диспропорции).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел решение.

```
//pattretn.vert
// Rotate texture
float uniformAngle = radians(u_rotation);
float tex_aspect =  u_tex_size.x/u_tex_size.y;
float cos_factor = cos(uniformAngle);
float sin_factor = sin(uniformAngle);

v_coord = vec2(v_coord.x *tex_aspect, v_coord.y) * mat2(cos_factor, sin_factor, -sin_factor, cos_factor);
v_coord.x *= 1.0 / tex_aspect;
```